Модуль PageSpeed для nginx
Наткнулся на статью по оптимизации битрикса (https://bazarow.ru/blog-note/9223/), где устанавливают специальный модуль page speed под Nginx, якобы повышающий число "попугаев" при тесте производительности через Google PageSpeed. Накатил модуль, модуль работает (в ответах сервера присутствует заголовок модуля ngx_pagespeed. Но на практике количество баллов при тестировании производительности не изменилось, хотя в той же статье обещали прирост чуть ли не в 2 раза. В чём может быть проблема? Попытался и +- какой-то конфиг сделать (хотя по умолчанию вроде как должна быть разница заметна):
pagespeed on;
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/cache/nginx; 
pagespeed FileCacheSizeKb 256000;
pagespeed FileCacheCleanIntervalMs 36000000;
pagespeed FileCacheInodeLimit      500000;
pagespeed RewriteLevel CoreFilters;
pagespeed EnableFilters combine_css,combine_javascript,defer_javascript,make_google_analytics_async,remove_comments,convert_png_to_jpeg,convert_jpeg_to_webp,collapse_whitespace;

Но и после этого ничего не поменялось, как было, так и осталось (может быть даже хуже стало).

P.S. Баллы эти нужны не для меня, а для заказчика. Сайт работает быстро, но им нужно чтоб это было видно в Google Page Speed, как-то так...

необходимо понять какие части контента страницы необходимо оптимизировать, возможно перенести скрипты js какие то участки сделать отложенную загрузку.
этот модуль возможно не все оптимизирует хорошо в авто режиме

Да это понятно, в отчёте всё пишут. Вот только столько времени убил на установку модуля, а толку от него никакого
